# Asking about the popularity of a package manager

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, on-topic

Is it on-topic for Super User to ask a question regarding the popularity/popular acceptance of a specific package manager (for Windows)?

Comment: Probably not as any answers would be opinion based.

Comment: Popularity is inherently based on the opinions and ideas of various groups of people and in my opinion would be off topic. How to use it is a matter of fact, asking what people think of it or how many people use it depends on the *people* in the groups you ask and is opinion based.

Comment: No idea why the two previous commenters think one can't objectively quantify popularity.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not - Super User is for technical questions. Asking about package manager's popularity is something between being opinion-based and a software recommendation, both of which are explicitly off topic for Suepr User.

Comment: The thing is, I'm wondering if it's "legit" enough for me to install it on a laptop which is going out as a donation, and its popularity or "PC user public regard" is a consideration I need to make.

Comment: @einpoklum to me this sounds like a question for [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)